# Ordered set AMPL

Tags: math, set, mathematical-optimization, ampl

I am trying to program a set, `F`, which contains subsets of unknown size in AMPL.

An example would be: `F1 = {2,3}`, `F2 = {5}`, `F3={4}`, `F4={5}`.

The complete set will be of the form `{(2,3),(5),(4),(5)}`.

I need the set to be organized in this way because I will use this set in a constraint where I will need to iterate for every `j` contained in the set `Fi`. So when `i=1`, `j` will iterate for `j=1,2` and so on.

Is there a way to program this set in AMPL?

I am working programming on assembly line balancing problems and will need this set to program the precedence constraints; ie. task 1 must happen before tasks 2 and 3, task 3 before 4, and task 2 and 4 before 5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can represent `F` as an [indexed set](http://ampl.com/BOOK/CHAPTERS/09-sets2.pdf#page=10) in AMPL:

```
set F{1..4};
data;
set F[1] = 2 3;
set F[2] = 5;
set F[3] = 4;
set F[4] = 5;
```